# Remove text of a field after last repeating character

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, t-sql, ssms

In T-SQL is there a way to take a field and make it return all the text up to (and including) a possibly repeating character?  The character that could be repeating is "-".  I can achieve this in Excel, but it would be so much better for me to do this on the query level.  Here is an example of what I would like to see for this field (part.partnum):

```
| Part.partnum      | Result      | 
| H24897-D-001      | H24897-D-   |
| BHF44-82-V-1325   | BHF44-82-V- |       
| BKNG5222          | BKNG5222    |        
| YAKJD-78AB        | YAKJD-      |
```

Please excuse my sad looking table, I'm not the best at formatting. I would be able to achieve the same result in Excel by using (assuming the part number I want to use is in cell A1 :

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",REPT(" ",255)),255)),"")
```

I hope this makes sense.  Thanks in advance for any help given.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Test Data

```
DECLARE @TABLE TABLE (partnum VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @TABLE VALUES       
('H24897-D-001'),
('BHF44-82-V-1325'),
('BKNG5222'),
('YAKJD-78AB')
```

### Query

```
SELECT   PartNum
        ,REVERSE(
                SUBSTRING(REVERSE(Partnum), 
              CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(Partnum)) 
               , LEN(Partnum) - CHARINDEX('-',REVERSE(Partnum)) + 1)
               ) AS Result
FROM @TABLE
```

### OUTPUT

```
╔═════════════════╦═════════════╗
║     PartNum     ║   Result    ║
╠═════════════════╬═════════════╣
║ H24897-D-001    ║ H24897-D-   ║
║ BHF44-82-V-1325 ║ BHF44-82-V- ║
║ BKNG5222        ║ BKNG5222    ║
║ YAKJD-78AB      ║ YAKJD-      ║
╚═════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the reverse function to flip it around.  That will allow you to find the last instance of the character you're looking for (it becomes the first).  Then it's a simple substring. (MID in Excel)

```
substring(partnum,1,len(partnum)-charindex("-",reverse(partnum))
```